# VueJS: How to pass interpolated variable as parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to pass the index of the `v-for` loop as a parameter in my `removeTask` function. How can I do this?

```
<ol class="list-group">
    <li v-for="task in tasks"
        class="list-group-item"> 
        {{ task.body }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="removeTask({{$index}})">x</button>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Suggestions pretty much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the brackets `{{ }}`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="removeTask($index)">x</button>
```